# lxml.etree._Element.append() from a loop not working as expected

Tags: python, lxml

I would like to know why in this code `append()` seems to work from inside the loop, but the resulting xml displays the modification from only the last iteration, while `remove()` works as expected. This is a overly simplified example, I'm working with big chunks of data, and need to append the same subtree to many different parents.

```
from lxml import etree

xml = etree.fromstring('<tree><fruit id="1"></fruit><fruit id="2"></fruit></tree>')
sub = etree.fromstring('<apple/>')

for i, item in enumerate(xml):
    item.append(sub)
    print('Fruit {} with sub appended: {}'.format(
        i, etree.tostring(item).decode('ascii')))

print('\nResulting tree after iterating through items with append():\n' +
    etree.tostring(xml, pretty_print=True).decode('ascii'))

for item in xml:
    xml.remove(item)

print('Resulting tree after iterating through items with remove():\n' +
    etree.tostring(xml, pretty_print=True).decode('ascii'))
```

Current output:

```
Fruit 0 with sub appended: <fruit id="1"><apple/></fruit>
Fruit 1 with sub appended: <fruit id="2"><apple/></fruit>

Resulting tree after iterating through items with append():
<tree>
  <fruit id="1"/>
  <fruit id="2">
    <apple/>
  </fruit>
</tree>

Resulting tree after iterating through items with remove():
<tree/>
```

Expected output from *after iterating through items with `append()`*:

```
<tree>
  <fruit id="1"/>
    <apple/>
  </fruit>
  <fruit id="2">
    <apple/>
  </fruit>
</tree>
```

Comment: also this works  in xml.etree.ElementTree unlike lxml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you only created *one instance* of `<apple/>` to be appended. So basically you just moved that one instance from one parent to another until the last `append(sub)` executed. Try to move creation of the `<apple/>` element within `for` loop instead :

```
for i, item in enumerate(xml):
    sub = etree.fromstring('<apple/>')
    item.append(sub)
    print('Fruit {} with sub appended: {}'.format(
        i, etree.tostring(item).decode('ascii')))
print()
```

**output :**

```
Resulting tree after iterating through items with append():
<tree>
  <fruit id="1">
    <apple/>
  </fruit>
  <fruit id="2">
    <apple/>
  </fruit>
</tree>
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Why does `print('Fruit {} with sub appended: {}'...` prints the correct output? I'm new to python, so this is some concept I don't yet understand!

Comment: OK, it actually modified every item, but then `<apple/>` got removed later, now I think I understand it! Thank you!

Comment: is there a way not to read xml from string per each iteration? my sub is already in etree format

Comment: EDIT fixed its `i.append(ET.fromstring(ET.tostring(sub)))`