# lxml xpath/findall and update

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to update an xml document to add a child element to a set of parent elements identified by an xpath.

To do this, I identify the elements I want to change by xpath, and then run a for loop over those elements. I'm calling this block of code the 'xpath for block'

I can:

- successfully identify the elements that need to be updated
- update the elements while in the 'xpath for block'
- update the root node while in the 'xpath for block'

I cannot:

- preserve the updates once leaving the 'xpath for block' (**EDIT** apart from the last element in the loop)

Code:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

def _modify_mods_content(mods_content):
    """Massage the MODS content before auto-populating page

    Args:
        mods_content (str): content of MODS datastream as a string

    Returns:
        updated_content (str): updated MODS content
    """
    nsmap = {'mods': NAMESPACES['mods']}

    mods_xml = ET.fromstring(mods_content)

    # Create empty given-name element
    given_name_tag = ET.QName(NAMESPACES['mods'], 'namePart')
    given_name = ET.Element(given_name_tag)
    given_name.attrib['type'] = 'given'


    # xpath to find every personal name that does not have a child 
    # given name element
    no_given_names_xpath = '//mods:name[@type="personal"][not(mods:namePart[@type="given"])]'


    for element in mods_xml.xpath(no_given_names_xpath, namespaces=nsmap):
        element.insert(0, given_name)

    new_string = ET.tostring(mods_xml)
    return new_string
```

If I put a pdb prompt into the xpath for block, I can see that the element is updating, and if I do a 'getparent' all the way up the tree, I can see that the root mods_xml document appears to be updated *for that instance only*.

Once I leave the for loop, none of the updates persist.

For example:

Original file:

```
<root>
  <mods:name type="personal">
    <mods:namePart type="family">Smith</mods:namePart>
  </mods:name>
  <mods:name type="personal">
    <mods:namePart type="family">Jones</mods:namePart>
  </mods:name>
</root>
```

First time in the xpath for block

```
<root>
  <mods:name type="personal">
    <mods:namePart type="given"></mods:namePart>
    <mods:namePart type="family">Smith</mods:namePart>
  </mods:name>
  <mods:name type="personal">
    <mods:namePart type="family">Jones</mods:namePart>
  </mods:name>
</root>
```

Second time in the xpath for block:

```
<root>
  <mods:name type="personal">
    <mods:namePart type="family">Smith</mods:namePart>
  </mods:name>
  <mods:name type="personal">
    <mods:namePart type="given"></mods:namePart>
    <mods:namePart type="family">Jones</mods:namePart>
  </mods:name>
</root>
```

**EDIT**: the following example originally had no inserted elements. These examples are simplified from a much longer and more complex document. I must have missed that the final update was being persisted after leaving the block.

Once I leave the block

```
<root>
  <mods:name type="personal">
    <mods:namePart type="family">Smith</mods:namePart>
  </mods:name>
  <mods:name type="personal">
    <mods:namePart type="given"></mods:namePart>
    <mods:namePart type="family">Jones</mods:namePart>
  </mods:name>
</root>
```

I realise the that this could be done with XSLT. I just want to know if there's a more 'pythonic' way.

I've actually (sort of) made it work, but it's such a horrible hack that a) I don't want to do it, b) it only works if all of the elements are at the same depth (which they happen to be in this instance, luckily):

```
    while mods_xml.xpath(no_given_names_xpath, namespaces=nsmap):
        elements = mods_xml.xpath(no_given_names_xpath, namespaces=nsmap)
        replacement_element = elements[0]
        replacement_element.insert(0, given_name)
        parent = elements[0].getparent()
        parent.replace(elements[0], replacement_element)
        new_xml_string = ET.tostring(parent, pretty_print=True)
        mods_xml = ET.fromstring(new_xml_string)
```

Any thoughts or comments would be very welcome!

Comment: Very probably a manifestation of the same problem, yes. A similar approach to fixing it worked (see commend below). I'd have no objections to this being marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the linked problem isn't likely to be found by people who have the problem I had. In both cases, the same thing causes a function to fail, however in each case it's a different function that fails.

It's only when you know what the solution is that the connection becomes apparent. I *did* search before posting the question, honest!

Answer (score 0):

A colleague who isn't on Stack Overflow has helpfully responded with the answer.

The issue is related to [this issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527392/). I had thought that the given_name element I was creating was a blank element I could add in to the parent document each time in the loop (as if I were doing string concatenation).

In fact, lxml treated the element as a distinct object, and was simply moving it around the file (the examples above were simplified, so I must have missed the last place the insertion was present).

The solution was to use a small private function to generate a new element each time.

The corrected code:

```
def _modify_mods_content(mods_content):
    """Massage the MODS content before auto-populating xml_ora

    Args:
        mods_content (str): content of MODS datastream as a string

    Returns:
        updated_content (str): updated MODS content
    """
    nsmap = {'mods': NAMESPACES['mods']}
    try:
        mods_xml = ET.fromstring(mods_content)

        def __create_empty_given_name_element():
            """Create empty given-name element

            Returns:
                given_name (ET.element): empty element for processing
            """
            given_name_tag = ET.QName(NAMESPACES['mods'], 'namePart')
            given_name = ET.Element(given_name_tag)
            given_name.attrib['type'] = 'given'
            given_name.text = ''
            given_name.tail = '\n      '
            return given_name

        # xpath to find every personal name that does not have a child given name element
        no_given_names_xpath = '//mods:name[@type="personal"][not(mods:namePart[@type="given"])]'

        for element in mods_xml.xpath(no_given_names_xpath, namespaces=nsmap):
            given_name_element = __create_empty_given_name_element()
            element.insert(0, given_name_element)

        return_text = ET.tostring(mods_xml)   
    except Exception as _:  # pylint: disable=W0703
        # Something went wrong, but try to let a human fix it
        # by returning original MODS
        return mods_content
    return return_text
```